# Saving specific attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I've an Outlook rule to run the following script when a specific email comes in.
I want the code to look in the specific folder, see if there is currently a file called CID.csv and if so delete it before saving the new CID.csv file into it.

Everything works except my line for saving the attachment.

The error I get is

> Object variable or With block variable not set.

What do I set objAtt to?

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim STRFileExists As String
Dim strName As String
Dim EmAttFile As String
Dim i As Long
Dim EmAttachCount As Long

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

saveFolder = "\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\Schedules\Nightly File Schedules\Deb's File Autosave\Extra Packs"
strFileName = "\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\Schedules\Nightly File Schedules\Deb's File Autosave\Extra Packs\CID.csv"
STRFileExists = Dir(strFileName)

Set EmAttach = item.Attachments
AttachCount = EmAttach.Count
    
For i = AttachCount To 1 Step -1

    ' Get the file name
    EmAttFile = EmAttach.item(i).FileName
    If EmAttFile = "CID.csv" Then
        
        If STRFileExists = "" Then
            'MsgBox "The selected file doesn't exist"
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Else
            MsgBox "The selected file exists"
            Kill "S:\NFInventory\groups\CID\Schedules\Nightly File Schedules\Deb's File Autosave\Extra Packs\CID.csv"
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If

    End If
Next i

ErrHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error Number:" & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
      "Error Description: " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `EmAttach.Item(i)` is the individual attachment.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks appreciate it. I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer per se, you may find a generic save attachment function useful:

> With it you can use or set a number of different options (such as only saving the ".pdf,.txt" files, or deleting any saved attachments or overwriting existing files)

> ***NB:*** you should actually be able to use `FileExtensions:="\CID.csv"` to save a specific file

```
Private Function SaveAttachments(ByVal Item As Object, FilePath As String, _
    Optional Prefix As String = "", _
    Optional FileExtensions As String = "*", _
    Optional Delimiter As String = ",", _
    Optional RemoveAttachments As Boolean = False, _
    Optional OverwriteFiles As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ExitFunction

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, FileName As String, Flag As Boolean
    Dim Extensions() As String: Extensions = Split(FileExtensions, Delimiter)
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

    For j = LBound(Extensions) To UBound(Extensions)
        With Item.Attachments
            If .Count > 0 Then
                For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
                    FileName = FilePath & Prefix & .Item(i).FileName
                    Flag = IIf(LCase(Right(FileName, Len(Extensions(j)))) = LCase(Extensions(j)), True, False)
                    Flag = IIf(FileExtensions = "*" Or Flag = True, True, False)
                    If Flag = True Then
                        If Dir(FileName) = "" Or OverwriteFiles = True Then
                            .Item(i).SaveAsFile FileName
                        Else
                            Debug.Print FileName & " already exists"
                            Flag = False
                        End If
                    End If
                    If RemoveAttachments = True And Dir(FileName) <> "" And Flag = True Then .Item(i).Delete
                Next i
            End If
        End With
    Next j
    SaveAttachments = True

ExitFunction:
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `objAtt` before to use it:

```
...
For i = AttachCount To 1 Step -1
    EmAttFile = EmAttach.item(i).FileName
    If EmAttFile = "CID.csv" Then   
 
       objAtt = EmAttach.item(i)       ' <---- Define objAtt before to use it

       If STRFileExists = "" Then
           'MsgBox "The selected file doesn't exist"
           objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
       Else
           MsgBox "The selected file exists"
           Kill "S:\NFInventory\groups\CID\Schedules\Nightly File Schedules\Deb's File Autosave\Extra Packs\CID.csv"
           objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
       End If

    End If
Next i
...
```